# AVERAGE NUMBER OF DAYS BETWEEN DATES

Tags: sql, date

I want to calculate the average of the date according to the number of days between Factor2 and Facort3 where the Factor1 Value is A

[image]

how can I do it, please ?

Comment: the idea is not clear !!! please try to describe it more.

Comment: Hello, please tell us what language you use.

Comment: I have data with three columns (Factor 1, Factor 2, and Factor 3) where factor 2 and 3 are dates. I want to get the number of days between the two dates then get the average.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 3):

[image: the values]

```
select avg(DATEDIFF(DAY,Factor2,Factor3)) from [TestingTable]
    where Factor1='A'
```

I've taken the difference between Factor2 and Factor 3 where Factor1 is A, then Find the average of the column.

and the result must be "3"

it's in SQL :
1- DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

2-AVG ( [ ALL | DISTINCT ] expression )

3- datepart : it could be Day Month, Year....etc

Comment: What is the command sir?

Comment: it's in SQL :
1- DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate ) 
2-AVG ( [ ALL | DISTINCT ] expression )
3- datepart :it could be Day Month , Year